# Databricks git integration, missing "Link git account" public preview option

Tags: git, github, databricks, azure-databricks

There is a feature in public preview for databricks that allows you to link a github respository to your Databricks workspace using the ['Databricks GitHub app'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/repos/get-access-tokens-from-git-provider#--link-github-account-using-databricks-github-app)

This feature "Link Git account" seems absent in some workspaces even though all workspace settings are the same, is there anything that needs to be activated in order for this feature to be available?

To illustrate this; on the right the "Link Git account" option is present, on the left it is missing.

[image: databricks user settings git integration example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to perhaps have been a fluke in the roll-out on Databricks side, atm I cannot reproduce a Databricks workspace *without* the github app integration option.

[image]